# Sharing data between controllers using promises?

Tags: angularjs

Okay, I have this function in a service:

```
wikiServices = angular.module('wikiServices', []);

wikiServices.factory('newsService', function($http, $q){
 var chosenNewsStory = "";

 var getNewsStory = function(news_id, callback){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "news/article/" + news_id
    })
    .success(function(newsStory){
        deferred.resolve(newsStory);
        console.log("RESOLVED " + newsStory);   
    });
    return deferred.promise;
 });
```

Controller 1:

```
wikiControllers =  angular.module('wikiControllers', []);
wikiControllers.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'newsService',
  function($scope, newsService){
   $scope.getNewsStory = newsService.getNewsStory(function(input){
     newsService.getNewsStory(news_id);
   };
});
```

Controller 2:

```
wikiControllers =  angular.module('wikiControllers', []);
wikiControllers.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'newsService',
  $scope.watch('newsService.chosenNewsStory', function(newVal){
     console.log(newVal);
  });
});
```

Now, I have tried setting "chosenNewsStory" in the service a lot of places buyt I think I'm missing a key part of the whole JS-"experience".

I'm having trouble setting "var chosenNewsStory" in the service to the newsStory fetched from the server. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: please show more code

Comment: Will do when I get home.

Comment: Okay, it's updated. :)

Comment: You have to `return `chosenNewsStory` from the service, else you won't have access to it, hence why your `$watch` isn't doing anything. I prefer returning `get` and `set` methods for variables that need to be shared.

Comment: I've managed to retrieve the variable but I can't set it. Where should I put the set-code?

I've tried to set chosenNewsStory = newsStory right before deferred.resolved() but I think it's a scope-thing.

Comment: In your service, return an object, and in that object, return all the methods you want to have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `get` and `set` methods for the variable that is being shared, and return these as well. I would format your service like so:

```
wikiServices.factory('newsService', function($http, $q){
    var chosenNewsStory = "";

    return {
        getNewsStory: function(news_id, callback){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "news/article/" + news_id
            }).success(function(newsStory){
                deferred.resolve(newsStory);
                console.log("RESOLVED " + newsStory);   
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getNews: function() {
            return chosenNewsStory;
        },

        setNews: function(story) {
            chosenNewsStory = story;
        }
    }
});
```

Now you will be able to watch `newsService.getNews()` and set it with `newsService.setNews(news)`

Comment: So should I use setNews in the controller calling getNewsStory?

Comment: Yep, that will set it in the service and your other controlls `$watch` (which should now watch `newsService.getNews()` ) should pick up the change.