# Combine JSON for two POST in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, post, controller

I am trying to combine response of one POST data with another input JSON so that it can do another POST function.

**Controller 1:-**

```
$scope.master = {};

     $scope.addChild = function(net) {
     $scope.master = angular.copy(net);
     $http.post("url",$scope.master).then( function(data) { 
    $scope.childData = data;
    $scope.dataName = $scope.master.Name;
         growl.success("Created a new Child");
         console.log(data);

     },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
           growl.error("Something went wrong");
    });
           console.log($scope.master);
};
```

Now I want to add the response of this controller ie; `$scope.segments = data;` to *2nd controller*:-

**Controller 2:-**

```
$scope.addOverall = {Child: []};        
             $scope.Create = function() {
         $http({
           method : 'POST',
           url : 'api',
          data : $scope.addOverall
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
           growl.success("Created a Table");    
            console.log(data);
        },function (data, status, headers, config) { 
           growl.error("Something is wrong");

     });

};
```

So now , my response data from *controller 1* must combine with 2nd controller input over here `{Child: []};` inside the **[ ]** How can I achieve that?

Comment: how about create a global variable and append the JSON for two post

Comment: ^ you mean [sharing the data between controllers with a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)?

Comment: @Lokesh right , for global variable $rootScope will be bad practise , using service I can achieve that , but how will I push the response to service and fetch only in this portion `[ ]` ?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey exactly

Comment: @WhoAmI read the Aleksey comment

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah kind of , my concern is how to pass the response data exactly inside this {Child: `[ ]`};

Comment: @WhoAmI you don't need to append the result of one post in a service's global variable and then append the result of another post in the same variable

Comment: @WhoAmI can you pass the promise from a service? e.g. `return $http.post("url", master).then((data) => {return data.data;})` and receive in another controller with `SharedService.postData(master).then((res)=>{$scope.addOverall.Child = res;})`

Comment: @Lokesh  I am just trying to append result of one POST that's it and too in the raw body for 2nd controller.

Comment: Aleksey has just wrote an answer for you

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Can you show me a work around. I never tried to post something from service. I need to check.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I tried but how will I push master in url in service , as master is user input json. ?

Comment: @WhoAmI possible with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855697/sharing-data-between-controllers-using-promises)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey This one is for GET which I am pretty familiar with in service. But for POST ,  I need to add raw body which master from click function.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller 1:**

**If you get result in data then use $rootscope for other variable**

```
$rootScope.myGlobalVariable = [] //if response is array or object

$http.post("url",$scope.master).then( function(data) { 
$rootScope.myGlobalVariable = data;
```

**Controller 2:**

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
$scope.mylocalVariable = data;
```

**final values in controller 2**

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.localVariable.length; i++)
{
  $rootScope.myGlobalVariable.push($scope.localVariable[i]);
}
console.log('combine json values', $rootScope.myGlobalVariable);
```

I hope this answer is work for You.
**Thanks**

Comment: Valuable suggestion , Thanks . I solved this problem already. Though I have to push in same controller function not in other.